# Is it possible to amplify 3w 4ohm speaker using any software?

Tags: audio, drivers, sound-card, speakers, amplification

My PC has integrated sound card. The interface of Audio output is "Realtek".
my speaker is "DAIN 4ohm 3watt"
https://www.adafruit.com/product/1314
and it has a controller with few capacitors, few resistors and it has potentiometer in order to increase or decrease volume.
(We know that we can increase or decrease volume without potentiometer as well. right!
 I mean using windows software!)

Also my speaker needs to be connected in to 220V outlet (or 110v outlet).
When I removed the adapter (800mA) which converts 220v AC (50Hz) to 10v AC (50Hz) and when I removed the Controller, I plug the "Realtek" cable (which include two wire +1.2v voltage and ground) into sound card which I have connected to "speaker 4ohm 3w" directly, it was working fine, but the volume was too low!
The volume was higher then traditional headphones have but using controller and adapter it had very high volume, almost 20 times higher!

So I need to know is it possible to amplify 3w 4ohm speaker volume which is directly connected to motherboard (Sound card) using any software?
Or does driver allow me to do such a job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 99.9% of cases it is not possible. The audio controller chip on your motherboard just can't deliver enough power. That "controller" thing was not actually a controller but a small power amplifier. Your audio chip is just not designed to drive a speaker directly and you can't overcome that. You shouldn't connect speakers directly to the audio output of your computer. You risk damaging it.

About these 0.1%... There are some sound cards that have a built in power amplifier but they are not very common. And I have seen onboard audio controller with built-in power amplifier just only once.

Answer (score 0):

if your running Windows 7 this might be an option to you (however I would Google search Software Amplifier for better results

http://windows7themes.net/en-us/4-ways-to-boost-your-sound-above-100-in-windows-7/